# Can't select the drive to install Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I followed a few tutorial on how to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10.

I created a partition(40GB) on my SSD. When I installed Ubuntu, I didn't select to install in a partition and selected the option to install alongside Windows.

Everything was great, until I went back to Windows and expanded my disk, removing the partition and apparently deleting Ubuntu but not the the Boot loader (Grub).

I once again followed a few guides and I think, I removed grub and Ubuntu. Now, I'm trying to install Ubuntu again and I am not getting the option to install it on my SSD, only on my HDD.

Do I need to actually create a partition for Ubuntu or what is going on?

Comment: Did you create the 40gb unallocated space again using Windows 10?

Comment: I didnt create it again no. Should create it again?

Comment: Yes! And don't delete it again using Windows after installing Ubuntu. Windows does not understand partition formats used by Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, got it working again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the mistake to delete the partition I created in Windows, to install Ubuntu in as I selected the option to install Ubuntu along side Windows and I thought the partition useless, so I deleted. Then whenever my pc booted, the bootloader, only displayed a console. I went through the process of deleting the bootloader from my EFI partition in Windows and then creating a new partition for Ubuntu.
TLDR: Make sure to delete the bootloader, create a new partition to install Ubuntu and don't delete it!